# How to add Emoji smileys for phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, emoji

I am trying to build an app like messenger. I have to add smileys for that like whatsapp.
For that i searched web and got [Github link for Emoji Icons](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon).
But it is for Android Native app.
I want to add this functionality in phonegap application. How can i do this. 
 1. Is there any other plugin for phonegap ?
 2. Can i modify the given library for adding it to phonegap application ?
 3. Or i have to build custom plugin for this ?

I am beginner in phonegap. Don't have idea in building plugins. Please help me by suggesting ideas and providing useful links.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it like that. in app you dont have access to native textview, you are working in webview.

Comment: how is this not an answer?

Comment: answer is "you CANT do it", I dont criticise people for not knowing something and negative answer is still an answer.

Comment: The question was "how do I do this?", and "it's not possible" is a perfectly valid answer to that question. It might not be what the asker wanted, but if it can't be done, then it can't be done.

Comment: @Log1cツ writing plugin will not help here, because, as I answered, OP wont have access to native textview, and plugins are created to make the bridge to native functionality, and creating a plugin is not really the meritum of question. Question was - how to add smiley to textView, and answer is - you dont have access to textView, thus cant add smiley to it. and please stop shouting, in my opinion 'you cant do it' (with explanation - why) is still more answer than comment.

Comment: Thanks for discussing my question. Now i know what plugins do. Thanks for increasing my knowledge by giving negative vote :P

Comment: well he can still use angularjs-emoji plugin to include popup in app and include emojis .. i think !